# Почему то не центрируется по горизонтали виджет комментариев "Вконтакте"

Tags: html, html5, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, виджет

Здравствуйте! Вставляю кусок кода, все работает, но выравнивание виджета по горизонтали происходит по левому краю. Пробовал использовать различные align, но почему то все игнорируется, ничего не пойму.
Вот скрин проблемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код html с использованием

:

```html
<t t-name="website.checkwidget">
    <t t-call="website.layout">
      <div id="wrap" class="oe_structure oe_empty"/>
      <!-- Put this script tag to the <head> of your page -->
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?122"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        VK.init({apiId: 1111111, onlyWidgets: true});
        </script>
      </head>
<!-- Put this div tag to the place, where the Comments block will be -->
<p align="center">
<div id="vk_comments"></div>
</p>
<p align="center">
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 10, width: "665", attach: "*"});
</script>
</p>
    </t>
</t>
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно задать:

```
#vk_comments { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Или так

```css
.vk-comment-container{
  max-width: 665px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#vk_comments,
#vk_comments iframe {
 width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?122"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        VK.init({apiId: 1111111, onlyWidgets: true});
        </script>
      

<div class="vk-comment-container">
<div id="vk_comments"></div>
</div>

<p align="center">
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 10, width: "100%", attach: "*"});
</script>
```